# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect - how to specify file path in properties file

Tags: java, properties

I am reading properties file to get a file path as below.

```
    String result = "";
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        String propFileName = "config.properties";

        inputStream = GetPropertyValues.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

        if (inputStream != null) {
            prop.load(inputStream);
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
        }
```

The properties file has the path specified like below.

```
configSettingsFilePath = C:\\\\ConfigSetting.xml
```

Now I get this below exception when I run my code saying file is not found.

```
Creating instance of bean 'configSettingHelper'
```

configSettingsFilePath = C:\ConfigSetting.xml
2017-09-18 14:47:00 DEBUG ConfigSettingHelper:42 - ConfigSettingHelper ::  ConfigSetting File:configSettingsFilePath = C:\ConfigSetting.xml
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Java\eclipse\eclipse\configSettingsFilePath = C:\ConfigSetting.xml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:246)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)

Instead of reading the path from properties file, if I directly use "C:\ConfigSetting.xml" in the code, it reads the file.

Can you please suggest what I should use in the properties file to specify the path?

Comment: Have you tried using forward slashes instead? e.g. `C:/ConfigSetting.xml`

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider you don't use forward slashes in Windows.

Comment: @AleksandrMukhalov Technically true, but not in the context of opening files in Java. Also, as for the question, if you're trying to open something in the root of `C:/`, it's possible your application may not be able to read it. Try moving it to a directory more likely to be read/writable, like `C:\Users\Username`

Comment: Try out saving the path in properties file without escaping the backslash. Like this: `configSettingsFilePath = C:\\ConfigSetting.xml`.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider there should be no problem using backslash on Windows when opening files in Java.

Comment: @AleksandrMukhalov I never said there was. It's just way more verbose when a single forward slash can be used.

Comment: Going all the way back to pre-Windows DOS, the filesystem calls would accept _either_ backslash `\\`` or slash `/` as the separator, it was `command.com` that would only accept backslash.  But I haven't checked lately.

Comment: I have tried forward slash too. Then I print out what I get in the java file, it correctly specifies the path I have in the properties file but still throws this exception.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the file only fails when the .jar is running.
Running the app from within Netbeans is fine. (Different path)

Also, the path is coming from

```
URL resourceURL = MyClass.class.getResource("mydir/myfile.txt");
```

Printing out the path is perfect.

Also, a mypicture.gif in the very same directory loads fine:

```
ImageIcon mypicture = new ImageIcon(imageURL, description)).getImage();
```

even when running the .jar. IE: the actual path must be fine.

It is only a text file I try reading via

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileName);
```

is when it fails - and only if it is in the jar.

Comment: Has anyone found an answer to this?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue .. Anyone has solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because `C:\` is not on the classpath. You're using `getClassLoader()` which presumably returns a `ClassLoader`.

[According to the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) for `ClassLoader#getResource`:

> This method will first search the parent class loader for the
>   resource; if the parent is null the path of the class loader built-in
>   to the virtual machine is searched. That failing, this method will
>   invoke findResource(String) to find the resource.

That file is in the root of the drive, which is not going to be on the classpath or the path of the class loader built-in to the VM. If those fail, `findResource` is the fallback. It's unknown where `findResource` looks without seeing the implementation, but it doesn't appear to pay attention to the `C:`.

The solution is to move the properties file into your classpath. Typically, you'd put property files like this in the `src/main/resources` folder.

Comment: Yes, this is what was working for me but when we deploy,I want the config file to be accessible to the user to update and so want to put it in a configurable path and hence I have the properties file above in the src/main/resources directory with the filepath to the user manipulated config file.

Comment: By the way, I upvoted your answer but since I am new, it doesn't show :)

Comment: Then you'll need to open the file manually, not via the classloader, and perhaps make the properties file location a launch parameter.

Comment: Ok. Will have to do that. Thanks!